# Python : Using one function to filter out a list present in another function

Tags: python, function

I have the following code:

```
from lxml import etree
from datetime import datetime

file = "Loja_mais_avancado.xml"
treeDoc = etree.parse(file)

listaUtilizadores = treeDoc.xpath("//Utilizador")
listaCompras = treeDoc.xpath("//compra")
listaProdutos = treeDoc.xpath("//produto")

for compra in listaCompras:
    data = compra.xpath("//compra/@data_de_compra")
    coid = compra.xpath("//compra/@coid")
    estado = compra.xpath("//compra/@estado")
    compradorId = compra.xpath("//compra/@id")
    rangeCompra = compra.xpath("count(//compra)")

for produto in listaProdutos:
    produtoId = produto.xpath("//produto/@iid")
    rangeProduto = produto.xpath("count(//produto)")

compradorId = [word.replace("U01", "Xavier Ribeiro André") for word in 
compradorId]
compradorId = [word.replace("U02", "Francisco Varela") for word in 
compradorId]
compradorId = [word.replace("U03", "Miguel Garcia") for word in compradorId]

compra = [0, 0, 0, 0]
produto = [0, 0, 0, 0]

for g in range(int(rangeCompra)):
    dataParsed = datetime.strptime(data[g], "%Y/%m/%d")
    compra[g] = (dataParsed.year, coid[g], compradorId[g], data[g], 
estado[g])

for p in range(int(rangeProduto)):
    dataParsed = datetime.strptime(data[p], "%Y/%m/%d")
    produto[p] = (dataParsed.year, coid[p], produtoId[p])

def compraPorAno(ano):
    print("Compras em:", ano)
    for (a, b, c, d, e) in compra:
        if ano == a:
            print("ID:", b)
            print("Comprador:", c)
            print("Data de inserção:", d)
            print("Estado de Compra:", e)
            produtosNasCompras(ano)

def produtosNasCompras(ano):
    for (a, b, c, d, e) in compra:
        for (f, g, h) in produto:
            if ano == f:
                if g == b:
                    print("  Produtos:", h)

compraPorAno(2017)
```

With the following output:

```
Compras em: 2017
ID: CO02
Comprador: Xavier Ribeiro André
Data de inserção: 2017/10/15
Estado de Compra: emExpedicao
  Produtos: I03
  Produtos: I01
  Produtos: I02
ID: CO03
Comprador: Miguel Garcia
Data de inserção: 2017/10/20
Estado de Compra: entregue
  Produtos: I03
  Produtos: I01
  Produtos: I02
ID: CO04
Comprador: Miguel Garcia
Data de inserção: 2017/10/20
Estado de Compra: entregue
  Produtos: I03
  Produtos: I01
  Produtos: I02
```

Is there anyway to assign a product ID (aka the "Produtos: I0#") to each part of the first function and therefore having an output such as:

```
Compras em: 2017
ID: CO02
Comprador: Xavier Ribeiro André
Data de inserção: 2017/10/15
Estado de Compra: emExpedicao
  Produtos: I03
ID: CO03
Comprador: Miguel Garcia
Data de inserção: 2017/10/20
Estado de Compra: entregue
  Produtos: I01
ID: CO04
Comprador: Miguel Garcia
Data de inserção: 2017/10/20
Estado de Compra: entregue
  Produtos: I02
```

Whilst still using 2 functions? So in a way associate each I0# to each result in the first function so only that one ID gets printed?

Comment: try `break` after the condition is met.

Comment: That makes me only get I03 in the output